# Error while parsing Json in swift 2.3

Tags: swift, swift2

I am trying to parse this NSDictionary

```
{"fare":{"value":99.03,"fare_id":"12313545861568689494880005558558852","expires_at":1485864494,"display":"\u20b999.03","currency_code":"INR"},"trip":{"distance_unit":"mile","duration_estimate":720,"distance_estimate":2.76},"pickup_estimate":2}
```

My code is:

```
 if let statusesArray = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [[String: Any]],
                    let user = statusesArray![0]["fare"] as? [String: Any],
                    let username = user["fare_id"] as? String {
                    // Finally we got the username
                }
                else
                {
                    print("DONE")
                }
```

But I am not getting the value fare ID. In fact its printing "DONE" from the else statement. I tried using apple's documentation of handling data,But the same error persist.

Comment: This is not an array, this is a dictionary.

Comment: I think @NiravD has posted the right way to solve this.

Comment: Beside the JSON Serialization part where Eric Aya pointed out that your JSON is a Dictionary at top level, with your kind of issue, you couldn't know where is lying your issue because you made "3 if" tests in one line. But it could be the last one (username) that went wrong, and you wouldn't have notice it.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't convert it into dictionary. Data is directly the response I get from server. Besides If u check in http://json.parser.online.fr its showing as valid JSON. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: What I'm telling you is that you are trying to access your content as if it were an array but it is actually not an array, it's a dictionary. This has nothing to do with the JSON being valid or not, this has nothing to do with the fact that you get it directly from the server.

Comment: Oops.Now i understood the concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `JSON` response is `Dictionary` not `Array`, so type cast it to `[String:AnyObject]` and then get `fare_id` from the nested `fare` Dictionary.

```
if let dict = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])) as? [String: AnyObject],
   let fareDict = dict["fare"] as? [String:AnyObject]
   let username = fareDict["fare_id"] as? String {
      print(username)
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: @Jeesson_7 Welcome mate :)